# ruby 1 line iterator with if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code appearing in an app and know there must be a more efficient way of writing it. The code looks through the active accounts and adds specific accounts to a new array. It works perfectly but I'm sure it's not the best way to do it.

```
@pending_expirations = []
Subscription.active.each do |subscription|
  if subscription.card_expiration_date.beginning_of_month == Date.today.beginning_of_month 
    @pending_expirations << subscription
  end
end
```

Can someone suggest a better way of iterating through this data?

Comment: thought about defining a scope, but "card_expiration_date" is a method on subscription model, not a field, and couldn't figure out how to define a scope that used both field values and methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby 'best practice' is clarity and readability over minimal code.  I would rethink your proposed implementation.  Your question states that you're looking for a more efficient way to write it - why not a method in the Subscription model?

```
#Subscription.rb

def pending_expirations
  self.select do |subscription|
    subscription.card_expiration_date.beginning_of_month == Date.today.beginning_of_month
  end
end
```

Then in your controller you can simply write the following:

```
@pending_expirations = Subscription.active.pending_expirations
```

Note that `active` is not included in the method - so you call it directly.  The benefit of this is that you can call `pending_expirations` on any subset of `Subscription`:

`Subscription.all.pending_expirations` to get all subscriptions that are expiring this month

`Subscription.gold.pending_expirations` to get all gold-level subscriptions that are expiring this month

...and so on

Comment: How do you understand that code is not inside any method ? :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit, it was in response to [the OP's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24672993/2128691)

Answer (score 2):

Do as

```
Subscription.active.select do |subscription|
   subscription.card_expiration_date.beginning_of_month == Date.today.beginning_of_month
end
```

Read this [`Enumerable#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) method.

Take this example :-

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 8, 9] 
a.select { |e| e.odd? } # => [1, 3, 9]
```

`#select` method pass each element to the block, then perform the conditional test, as you set. If the condition evaluates to `true`, then it puts, the current passed element to the *array*( which will be finally returned after all iteration completes), otherwise not.

Comment: sorry , can you explain a little more?

Answer (score 2):

You can write one line expression like this:

```
@pending_expirations = []
Subscription.active.each do |subscription| 
    @pending_expirations << subscription if subscription.card_expiration_date.beginning_of_month == Date.today.beginning_of_month
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a 1 line solution. Arup put me onto it

This is what I came up with

```
@pending_expirations = Subscription.active.select { |subscription| subscription.card_expiration_date.beginning_of_month == Date.today.beginning_of_month}
```

Comment: OMG! One line means this ? ROFL.